# Add annotate plugin to pom

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml, annox

I cannot add it to my project. I copied the config from the github repo.
Does anyone know what else to do?

UPDATE: after editing "groupId" and adding "version" (A_Di-Matteo) I get a new exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>x</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-jdk</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>API-support</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>API support</name>
    <description>Supporting library for APIs.</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.111-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                        <include>search/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>i18n/*.xsd</include>
                        <include>response/*.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>*.jxb</include>
                        <include>search/*.jxb</include>
                        <include>i18n/*.jxb</include>
                        <include>response/*.jxb</include>
                    </bindingIncludes>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-annotate-plugin-test-annox-annotations</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-package</id>
                        <!-- We need to do it at this late stage as we need compiled classes! -->
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the exception:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
 (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ave80/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:674)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:612)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:568)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:554)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:798)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:281)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:998)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:994)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core.TypeInfoSet
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 82 more
    pom.xml /API-support    line 66 Maven Build Problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `artifactId` of the plugin defined in your pom (and confirmed by the reported error log) is:

```
<artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
```

However, the correct one would be:

```
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

You basically made a typo, an additional `2`.

Moreover, from your error log, you would use version [`0.9.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.9.1), which is quite old (from 2014).

The latest one is [`0.13.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1) (from 2015), also used in its [github example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L131):

> `<maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.13.1</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>`

---

The next issue you are having:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core.TypeInfoSet
```

Has already been [reported](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/59) and it's mainly a dependencies issue. The class is provided by the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is actually also used by the github example, [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L204), for the [same version](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L129) as part of the its `dependencyManagement` section.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information. I added the lines and now I get a new exception. Please take a look, I updated the code.

Comment: I'm sure artifact [maven-jaxb22-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-jaxb22-plugin%22) is also valid.

Comment: @ulab nice find, apparently the have exactly the same GAV (Maven coordinates) except for that additional `2`, which is not a typo then. Wondering whether the content of the jar would also be the same (and why then having such a similar GAV)

Comment: agreed. I think it might have been version to differntiate between 2.2 and 2.1 but then 2 is maintained for some historical reason. may be @lexicore can throw some light.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the version of `annotate` plugin as below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jaxb-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.xsd</include>
                    <include>search/*.xsd</include>
                    <include>i18n/*.xsd</include>
                    <include>response/*.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>*.jxb</include>
                    <include>search/*.jxb</include>
                    <include>i18n/*.jxb</include>
                    <include>response/*.jxb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <configuration>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            </args>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- this plugin is used to add annotation for the models -->
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-annotate-plugin-test-annox-annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```